# R: flattening data table groups and creating a data table out of them

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a data table that looks like the one below

```
       datecolumn hourcolumn daycolumn   V  h  m dir_0 dir_15 dir_30 dir_45
    1: 2014.01.02      08:00         4  83  8  0     1     NA     NA     NA
    2: 2014.01.02      08:15         4  72  8 15    NA     -1     NA     NA
    3: 2014.01.02      08:30         4  60  8 30    NA     NA      0     NA
    4: 2014.01.02      08:45         4 107  8 45    NA     NA     NA     -1
    5: 2014.01.02      09:00         4 443  9  0    -1     NA     NA     NA
  ---                                                                     
40831: 2016.11.17      20:45         4 490 20 45    NA     NA     NA     -1
40832: 2016.11.17      21:00         4 461 21  0     1     NA     NA     NA
40833: 2016.11.17      21:15         4 502 21 15    NA      1     NA     NA
40834: 2016.11.17      21:30         4 441 21 30    NA     NA      1     NA
40835: 2016.11.17      21:45         4 617 21 45    NA     NA     NA      1
```

For every date there may be more hours of observation and each hour has one entry every 15 minutes.

What I need to do is "flatten out" the DT achieving this result

```
   datecolumn  h  m dir_0 dir_15 dir_30 dir_45
1: 2014.01.02  8  0     1     -1      0     -1
2: 2014.01.02  9  0    -1     -1      1     -1
3: 2014.03.09  9  0     1      1     -1     -1
.
.
.
```

I've tried this code

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x), by=list(datecolumn, h), .SDcols = c("dir_0", "dir_15", "dir_30", "dir_45")]
```

but it gives me the following:

```
    datecolumn  h  m dir_0 dir_15 dir_30 dir_45
 1: 2014.01.02  8  0     1     NA     NA     NA
 2: 2014.01.02  8 15    NA     -1     NA     NA
 3: 2014.01.02  8 30    NA     NA      0     NA
 4: 2014.01.02  8 45    NA     NA     NA     -1
 5: 2014.01.02  9  0    -1     NA     NA     NA
 6: 2014.01.02  9 15    NA     -1     NA     NA
 7: 2014.01.02  9 30    NA     NA      1     NA
 8: 2014.01.02  9 45    NA     NA     NA     -1
 9: 2014.03.09  9  0     1     NA     NA     NA
10: 2014.03.09  9 15    NA      1     NA     NA
11: 2014.03.09  9 30    NA     NA     -1     NA
12: 2014.03.09  9 45    NA     NA     NA     -1
 .
 .
 .
```

I could subset and extract from it with a cycle but it's far from elegant and quick

In the output above every row is a single entry from dir_X columns and not a group with all the dir_X sharing the same datecolumn and h so that calling DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x), by=list(datecolumn, h), .SDcols = c("dir_0", "dir_15", "dir_30", "dir_45")][1] would have returned a list, I think:

```
[[1]]
      datecolumn  h  m dir_0 dir_15 dir_30 dir_45
[1,]  2014.01.02  8  0     1     NA     NA     NA
[2,]  2014.01.02  8 15    NA     -1     NA     NA
[3,]  2014.01.02  8 30    NA     NA      0     NA
[4,]  2014.01.02  8 45    NA     NA     NA     -1
```

Being able to get the desired output in one step would be the best but also this second way of organize data could be a good start.
Any suggestion on how to deal with this?
Thank you very much.
Diego

Comment: In the code, you are just doing an identity operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dplyr based solution (at least I think this is what you are trying to do):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(datecolumn, h) %>% 
  summarise(dir_0 = mean(dir_0, na.rm = T),
            dir_15 = mean(dir_15, na.rm = T),
            dir_30 = mean(dir_30, na.rm = T),
            dir_45 = mean(dir_45, na.rm = T)
        )
```

Assumes your data frame is called df and there only being one value per hour per slot.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I need! 
I've never used dplyr, I think that the power of operator %>% makes it worth to do as := does in data.table...
I suppose you used the mean function just to quickly filter a vector containing only one meaningful value, isn'it?
Thank you very much for your help.